# Avoid 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Tags: mysql, installation

How can I get mysql installed and able to use it?

I've tried:

```
$ brew install mysql
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mysql-5.7.9.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-5.7.9.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring mysql-5.7.9.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

To connect:
    mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mysql now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  mysql.server start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.9: 12629 files, 464M
$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
 SUCCESS! 
$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
$
```

Answer (score 5):

For me turns out i already had mysql somewhere on my computer so a password was set there or something. After spending hours trying every solution out there this is what worked for me:

```
$ brew services stop mysql
$ pkill mysqld
$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql/ # NOTE: this will delete your existing database!!!
$ brew postinstall mysql
$ brew services restart mysql
$ mysql -uroot
```

all credit to @Ghrua

Comment: or mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, this is how i solved it (but only try this if you have no data in your db!!):

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
mysqld --initialize
```

The initialize method will create the data dir, and also an root user with a temporary password, be sure you copy this password, and than login and change the password.

Comment: This solution just worked for me. I had the same issue: installed MySQL via Homebrew and couldn't access it via root and no password. 


After running the above three lines and then reconnecting via `mysql -uroot -p` and using the password that was spit out via the `mysqld` command from previously, I got in. The last step for me was to reset the password to be blank within mysqld: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';`

Answer (score 0):

Try in CLI :

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

You need to specify that this user has a password.

Comment: I did that but I don't know the pw to use.  `$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
`

Comment: You need the root password of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Using `mysqld --initialize` worked for me. I just had to cut-n-paste the password from the below output.

`[Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: ?(A+3F48ed.Y`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this commande:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

then Enter password:*******